# JPA 2.0, Write query with multiple conditionals

Tags: java, jpa, hibernate-criteria

I have an entity with some fields

```
@Entity
public MyEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long id;

    public UUID uuid;

    public String value;

    .....

}
```

Now i would like to create a query which returns 1 if there are at least X entities in database with same uuid, or returns 2 if there are at least Y entities with same uuid and have same value. Im not sure if i described it well. If i would like to do it in java with a collection it would be like following code:

```
int b = 0;
String Y = ..;
UUID X = ...;
List<MyEntity> list = getAllEntitiesWithSameUUID(X)
if (list.sze() == 50) return 1 
for (MyEntity e : list) {
    if (e.value.equalsIgnoreCase(Y)) {
        b++;
        if (b == 100) {
            return 2;
        }
    }
}
```

In my case i have to process tons of data, i would like to move all processing to database server and in my application only retrieve an integer as a result of query.

Can i use JPA's Query, CriteriaQuery, (something else) to achieve this?
I'm using Jpa 2.0, and Hibernate 4.

Comment: I think your best bet is to use a native query.

Answer (score 0):

I would use two queries and combine both in Java:

```
String value = ..;
UUID uuid = ...;

Number uuidCount = entityManager.createQuery(
        "SELECT COUNT(e) FROM MyEntity e WHERE e.uuid = :uuid").setParameter(
        "uuid", uuid).getSingleResult();
if (uuidCount.longValue() == 50) {
    return 1;
}

Number uuidAndValueCount = entityManager.createQuery(
        "SELECT COUNT(e) FROM MyEntity e WHERE e.uuid = :uuid AND e.value = :value").setParameter(
        "uuid", uuid).setParameter("value", value).getSingleResult();
if (uuidAndValueCount.longValue() == 100) {
   return 2;
}
```

I think that the performance difference of one *catch it all* query compared to two separate queries is minimal. Depending on the execution plan it may even happen that this solution is faster, as you need to fire the second query only, if the first fails.